# 'textStorage' is a get-only property - Error when using MarkdownKit Framework for UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, markdown

I am trying to better understand Markdown support with a test project. I am using the `MardownTextView` project for a guide - found here https://github.com/indragiek/MarkdownTextView.

I have added the `MarkdownKit` framework to my test project.

The difference between my `textViewExample` project and the `MarkdownTextView` project is that I am adding the `UITextView` within the storyboard and the `MarkdownTextView` adds it programatically.

Here's how the `MarkdownTextView` project adds the `UITextView` and markdown support using the framework.

```
import UIKit
import MarkdownTextView

class ViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let attributes = MarkdownAttributes()
    let textStorage = MarkdownTextStorage(attributes: attributes)
    do {
        textStorage.addHighlighter(try LinkHighlighter())
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("Error initializing LinkHighlighter: \(error)")
    }
    textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownStrikethroughHighlighter())
    textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownSuperscriptHighlighter())
    if let codeBlockAttributes = attributes.codeBlockAttributes {
        textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownFencedCodeHighlighter(attributes: codeBlockAttributes))
    }

    let textView = MarkdownTextView(frame: CGRectZero, textStorage: textStorage)
    textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(textView)

    let views = ["textView": textView]
    var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-20-[textView]-20-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-20-[textView]-20-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)
}
}
```

**Test Project**

I have already added my `UITextView` to the view controller within the storyboard and the constraints. So I tried to add support by doing the following;

```
import UIKit
import MarkdownKit

@IBOutlet weak var textView:  MarkdownTextView!
var textStorage: MarkdownTextStorage?

class TextViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let attributes = MarkdownAttributes()
    let textStorage = MarkdownTextStorage(attributes: attributes)
    do {
        textStorage.addHighlighter(try LinkHighlighter())
    } catch let error {
        fatalError("Error initializing LinkHighlighter: \(error)")
    }
    textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownStrikethroughHighlighter())
    textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownSuperscriptHighlighter())
    if let codeBlockAttributes = attributes.codeBlockAttributes {
        textStorage.addHighlighter(MarkdownFencedCodeHighlighter(attributes: codeBlockAttributes))
    }

    //Error - Apply textStorage to textview that has already  been created
    textView.textStorage = textStorage

}
}
```

however I get the error

> Cannot assign to property: 'textStorage' is a get-only property

How can I add the markdown support for the `textView` in my project using the framework as the example project has already done, without programatically adding a `UITextView` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the textView's `layoutManager` to handle its `TextStorage`:

```
if let lm = self.textView.layoutManager{
  lm.replaceTextStorage(textStorage)
}
```

You can read more about that in Apple's documentation for the [`NSLayoutManager` class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSLayoutManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)NSLayoutManager)